# sql server select within select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

say I have the following query:

```
    select ID, ActualDate, DueDate
    from table1
```

What I need to do is to add another field called Flag 
which will be marked as "Y" if ActualDate is greater than DueDate

```
    select ID, ActualDate, DueDate,
     CASE  
      WHEN ActualDate > DueDate THEN 'Y' 
     ELSE 'N' 
      END as Flag 
     from table1
```

The above won't work as I get invalid column name ActualDate. Invalid column name DueDate.
What I need to do is a select within a select like this:

```
    select ID, ActualDate, DueDate, 
    CASE  
     WHEN ActualDate > DueDate THEN 'Y' 
     ELSE 'N' 
    END as Flag  
    from
    (select ID, ActualDate, DueDate
     from table1) tbl1 
     )
```

Comment: What doesn't work in the `case` version?  Your last query should work if you remove the superfluous `)` at the end

Comment: Why doesn't the first version work?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I get invalid column name ActualDate. Invalid column name DueDate - please advise

Comment: @NatePet Post the actual query then.  If your first query works then I can't see how those columns (`ActualDate`, `DueDate`) don't exist on `table1`.

Comment: @NatePet . . . If so, then your first query should not work.  The column names need to be what is in the table.  Perhaps you should include a list of all the columns in the table in your question.

Comment: @NatePet - double check the field names.  Could they be `actual_date` or `actual date`?  If the latter make sure to use [] to protect the name `[actual date]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table has the fields in it, then the following should work without the need for a subquery:

```
select ID, 
    ActualDate, 
    DueDate,
    CASE  
        WHEN ActualDate > DueDate 
        THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N' 
    END as Flag 
FROM table1
```

You can use a subquery but it is unnecessary:

```
select ID, 
    ActualDate, 
    DueDate, 
    CASE  
        WHEN ActualDate > DueDate 
        THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N' 
    END as Flag  
FROM
(
    select ID, ActualDate, DueDate
    from table1
) tbl1
```

Comment: Flag is actually a field not in the table but one that I created on the fly. Only ID, ActualDate, DueDate are in the table. Flag is not - please advice

Comment: That doesn't matter, you are using the `ActualDate` and `DueDate` field values to create the `Flag` column. What are the names of your fields?